# undefined local variable or method <object> for #<Class:0x55ebe50>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I have problems with polymorphic in Rails.

I have this files:

```
class CreateExecutions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :executions do |t|
      t.integer :player_space_id
      t.integer :what_id
      t.references :what, polymorphic: true 
      t.integer :qty
      t.integer :level
      t.datetime :when_ready

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
class Execution < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :what, :polymorphic => true
end
```

---

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :game_space
    has_many :levels
    has_many :player_elements
    has_many :executions, :as => what
end
```

---

```
class PlayerSpace < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :game_space
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :executions, as: :what
end
```

---

And when I run a controller which has Element, I have this error:

NameError in PlayerSpacesController#show 
undefined local variable or method `what' for #

May you help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a slight typo in the `Element` class:
Change this:

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_many :executions, :as => what
end
```

To this:

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_many :executions, :as => :what
end
```

E.g you are missing a colon for 'what' which means it's not a symbol and instead is a variable or method. As you don't have a variable or method named `what`, Ruby is throwing the 'unnamed variable or method' error.